# Using unity c# i want to toggle on or off a GameObject with all of it's components inside

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
public GameObject CombactObject; //i have attached the prefab to this, in the inspector

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C))
    {
        ToggleCombactMode();

        Debug.Log("Combact should trun off/on");
    }
}

public void ToggleCombactMode()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C))
    {
        CombactObject.//donno what to put after
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the object to active or inactive using [`SetActive`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SetActive.html) and as parameter you simply invert its current own active state [`activeSelf`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject-activeSelf.html)

```
public void ToggleCombactMode()
{
    // No need to check for the input again
    CombactObject.SetActive(!CombactObject.activeSelf);
}
```